# How to calculate difference from a reference instrument?

Tags: measurement-error

I have a cheap thermometer and I would like to calculate its difference from a high-quality reference thermometer when measuring the same quantity, say the temperature in an oven. Is the recommended form of the difference, in terms of the sign and normalization of the error, as follows:

```
100*(Tcheap - Treference)/Treference
```

So a -5% difference would mean Tcheap is too low, for example.

Comment: Do you have any reason to believe this variation is non-linear? Otherwise, the difference sounds like a simple-enough but, straightforward approach.

Comment: It's linear. Thank you for the validation!